# hibernate c3p0 (пул соединений )

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

пул соединений в `Glassfish` и `Hibernate` (c3p0). они связаны между собой?

т.е не могу понять если в моем приложении есть связь с БД то все настройки пишу в hibernate.cfg.xml и все?

а сервер приложений об этом даже не знает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взаимодействие Glassfish с приложениями на нем происходит по JNDI. По этой же технологии настраивается connection pool. Пример посмотрите [тут](http://smeshkov.blogspot.com.by/2012/04/glassfish-312-hibernate-connection.html)